# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в предложении (прямая речь внутри авторских слов)?

Tags: пунктуация

Многократно повторяющаяся фраза «Hello. How are you?», – исходящая из уст представителей офиса, и столько же раз звучавший ответ клиентов «Fine!» – в конце дня слились для меня в единое целое, крутившееся в голове как заезженная пластинка. Word требует поставить пробел (you? », ) между вопросительным знаком и закрывающейся кавычкой.

Answer (score 1):

Ой нет! Перебор знаков.

*Многократно повторяющаяся фраза «Hello. How are you?», исходящая из уст представителей офиса, и столько же раз звучавший ответ клиентов «Fine!» в конце дня слились для меня в единое целое, крутившееся в голове как заезженная пластинка.*

Вот так достаточно.

**[Правило:](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827535.html)**

> Подлинные выражения, вставленные в текст в качестве элементов
>   предложения, выделяются кавычками, но двоеточие перед ними не
>   ставится: *Это «не хочу» поразило Антона Прокофьевича* (Г.);
>   *Предположение дневального, что  «взводный нажрался и дрыхнет где-то в избе»,  всё больше собирало сторонников* (Ф.); *Он вспомнил пословицу 
>   «За двумя зайцами погонишься — ни одного не поймаешь» и отказался от
>   первоначального плана; С криком «Спасайте детей!» юноша бросился в
>   горящее здание.*

Запятая после кавычки не требуется, если ей предшествует знак вопроса, восклицания или многоточие.

Да, и кто нам Word, чтобы что-то требовать, тем паче пробел между знаком и закрывающей кавычкой?!

Comment: Galina Avanesova: _Многократно повторяющаяся фраза «Hello. How are you?», исходящая из уст представителей офиса, и столько же раз звучавший ответ клиентов «Fine!» **в конце дня** слились для меня в единое целое_... === 


Здесь непонятно, с какими словами сочетается обстоятельство "в конце дня". Возможны варианты: 1) _**повторяющаяся** (фраза) и **звучащий** (ответ) когда?_ – в конце дня; 2) _**слились** когда?_ – в конце дня. === Лучше, на мой взгляд, поставить это обстоятельство чуть дальше: _...слились для меня **в конце дня** в единое целое_.

Comment: Слава, спасибо! Вопрос был исключительно о знаках. Меня в предложении всё устраивает: не "когда" и "когда", а в конце дня (когда) слились как что (заезженная пластинка).